# xbuild , googleplayservices - errors

Tags: android, google-play-services, xbuild, search-path

I am trying to use xbuild to build using command line on a mac os box - the build is for android, the app contains a reference to 'GooglePlayServicesLib' , 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'  and a few other libraries.

However when the application tries to build it comes back with unable to resolve these references, I have listed the snippet below. 
I can see that it is trying to search it in a few places, however not where the Android SDK Manager deploys the libs. I think I need to somehow specify for it to search at the correct location.

Could someone please tell me
a. If my assumption is correct
b. How can I force the build process to search in the correct location.

Regards
Rajesh

```
[16:13:51][Step3/3] /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.6/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'GooglePlayServicesLib' not resolved

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered ../Components/googleplayservicesgingerbread-13.0/lib/android/GooglePlayServicesLib.dll, but it does not exist.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3, assembly named 'GooglePlayServicesLib' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0, assembly named 'GooglePlayServicesLib' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/, assembly named 'GooglePlayServicesLib' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {PkgConfig}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered GooglePlayServicesLib, but could not find in any pkg-config files.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {GAC}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered GooglePlayServicesLib, but could not find in the GAC.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {RawFileName}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath bin/Debug/

[16:13:51][Step 3/3] /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.6/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' not resolved

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered ../Components/googleplayservicesgingerbread-13.0/lib/android/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll, but it does not exist.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {PkgConfig}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, but could not find in any pkg-config files.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {GAC}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, but could not find in the GAC.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {RawFileName}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath bin/Debug/

[16:13:51][Step 3/3] /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.6/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' not resolved

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered ../Components/googleplayservicesgingerbread-13.0/lib/android/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll, but it does not exist.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/, assembly named 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' not found.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {PkgConfig}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, but could not find in any pkg-config files.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {GAC}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                Considered Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, but could not find in the GAC.

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath {RawFileName}

[16:13:51][Step 3/3]                For searchpath bin/Debug/
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems that you did not have Mono.Android installed properly.

Did you install according to the following article?

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/mac/